# eureka force service registration from application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I want to register in my Eureka instance a ElasticSearch service (and some others) with a hardcoded IP.

The idea here is that my other services (like Zuul) could access those services using ribbon.

It would be optimal to set those services in my Eureka's application.yml

Is it possible? And how?

Comment: maybe Prana (https://github.com/Netflix/Prana) can help you with that? I never used it, tho, I just know it exists

Comment: @LuizE. Thanks for the tip! I'll keep it in mind for non Java applications that need to be more integrated in the project. I was looking for a simpler solution, just to have listed some services that my system uses, but are not that central or mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a feature that eureka supports.